On an equality obtained from analysis of an algorithm
I came across the following equality $$\Big(\frac{c n^b}{x}\Big)^{dx}=n^{n/x}$$ where $b,c,d\geq0$ are fixed and $n$ increases when I was analyzing an algorithm.
What is a good approximation for $O(n^{n/x})$? Is it $poly(n)$ or $quasipoly(n)$ or is it just $2^{n^a}$ at a fixed $0<a<1$?

how to make sense of this equality? how is $d$ related to $b,b',c$ ?

$d$, $b$, $b'$, $c$ are reals which are fixed. $x$ is parameter to be optimized.

I think it is just $O(2^{\sqrt{n}})$.

Do you mean that $x=x(n)$ is a solution to the given equation, and you need to bound $n^{n/x(n)}$ as $n$ grows?

The equation can be solved explicitly in terms of Lambert W function, which then enables accurate approximation of $n^{n/x}$.
Let's introduce $y:=x^2$ to rewrite the equation as
$$\Big(\frac{y}{c^2 n^{2b}}\Big)^{-dy/2}=n^n$$
and thus
$$\Big(\frac{y}{c^2 n^{2b}}\Big)^{y/(c^2n^{2b})}=n^{-2n^{1-2b}/(dc^2)},$$
implying that
$$y = \frac{-2n}{d}\log(n) / W(\frac{-2n^{1-2b}}{dc^2}\log(n))$$
and thus
$$\frac{n}x\log(n) = \big( -\frac{d}2 n\log(n) W(\frac{-2n^{1-2b}}{dc^2}\log(n))\big)^{1/2}.$$
Assuming that $b>1/2$, we can approximate $W(z)$ for $z<0$ as $\log(-z)$ to get
$$\frac{n}x\log(n) \approx \big(d(b-\frac12) n \big)^{1/2}\log(n)$$
and then
$$n^{n/x}\approx n^\sqrt{d(b-\frac12) n}.$$
This estimate can be made rigorous but I leave it here just as an idea.
